# Unable to create lockable file permission to create files in this location

Tags: php, laravel, docker, permissions

Иногда при отправке запроса с телефона на сервер получаю следующую ошибку:

«Unable to create lockable file: /app/storage/framework/cache/data/9f/9e/9f9e69bf9efaa71adba7f1bdeb3bc8a90a43940c. Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location»

Никак не могу понять и отловить последовательность действий - обычно это происходит при выполнении запроса регистрации пользователя. Происходит ошибка очень и очень редко.  Почему пишу что именно с приложения так как через постман отловить не удалось еще не разу.

При выполнении команды ls -l /app/storage/framework/cache/data/ получаю права доступа «drwxrwxrwx»

Если я правильно понимаю:

"rwxrwxrwx" означает, что у владельца, группы и остальных пользователей есть полные права чтения (r), записи (w) и выполнения (x).

В чем может быть проблема ?

Причем метод регистрации отрабатывает прекрасно, выдает bearer токен и на последующие запросы уже с токеном происходят проблемы.